# Инженерный калькулятор. Подскажите,как реализовать рекурсию по заданию

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия, калькулятор

Дано такое задание:

> Написать программу для вычисления арифметического выражения, которое введено с клавиатуры. Выражение может содержать числа (в т.ч. в экспоненциальной форме, например 1.2е-10), символы арифметических операций, скобки, функции 
>   sin, cos, tan, log, exp. Разбор выражения рекомендуется проводить след. образом. Создается рекурсивная функция gtoken(). В зависимости от текущего символа входной строки она производит следующие действия: +, -, /, * -> gtoken(); выполнить операцию цифра -> положить в стек цифру ( -> gtoken(); пропустить ) символ -> выяснить что за функция; gtoken(); вычислить значение

Не могу сообразить, как лучше реализовать работу рекурсивной функции. Подскажите и/или напишите пример (python), как это может выглядеть, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно разобраться в теме для начала. Советую начать с базовой информации про [синтаксический](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) и [лексический анализ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7), также про [АСТ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Вообще, тема не самая простая, для реальных языков существуют готовые мощные и кастомизируемые парсеры, которым скармливается описание грамматики нужного языка. Но работает они по тем же принципам.

Накидал простой пример парсинга математических выражений с комментариями и указанием моментов на улучшение. Без сложного анализа и АСТ, всё рассчитывается на лету.

```py
import operator, math

# Доступные операторы
## Поддерживаются только односимвольные
OPS = {
    '-': operator.sub,
    '+': operator.add,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}
# Доступные функции
FUNCS = {
    'sin': math.sin,
    'cos': math.cos,
}


def calc(token):
    try:
        # Парсим одно число
        return float(token)

    except ValueError:
        begin = token.find('(')
        if begin == 0 and token[-1] == ')':
            # Парсим просто выражение в скобках
            return parse(token[1:-1])

        elif begin > 0 and token[-1] == ')':
            # Парсим функцию
            name = token[0:begin]
            if name not in FUNCS:
                raise ValueError('Unknown function %s' % name)
            # TODO: можно парсить много аргументов умно разделяя по запятой
            arg0 = parse(token[begin+1:-1])
            result = FUNCS[name](arg0)
            # print('%s = %s' % (token, result))
            return result

        else:
            # Неизвестный токен
            # TODO: можно встроить константы/переменные
            raise ValueError('Unknown token %s' % repr(token))


def parse(txt):
    """
    Рассчитывает выражение и возвращает числовой результат
    # TODO: нет приоритета операторов
    """
    # Текущий токен
    token = ''
    # Уровень вложенности
    ## Вложненые выражения рассчитываются рекурсивно
    depth = 0
    # Текущий оператор
    op = None
    # Итоговое значение
    current_value = None

    def close_token():
        # Эта функция закрывает текущий токен
        # и сразу производит вычисления
        nonlocal token, op, current_value
        if token != '':
            if current_value is None:
                # Первый токен, его просто сохраняем
                current_value = calc(token)
            else:
                # Применяем оператор
                current_value = OPS[op](current_value, calc(token))
                # Обнуляем оператор
                op = None
            print(op, token, current_value)
            token = ''

    # Обрабатываем выражение посимвольно
    for c in txt:
        if depth > 0:
            # Если внутри скобок
            if c == ' ':
                # Пробелы не нужны
                continue
            token += c
            if c == ')':
                # Возвращаемся на уровень выше
                depth -= 1
                close_token()

        elif c == '(':
            # Удём внутрь скобок
            if token == '':
                # Это для фунций – имя функции и скобки
                # должны идти единым токеном
                close_token()
            depth += 1
            token += c

        else:
            # Парсим токен
            if c == ' ':
                # Пробелы не нужны
                continue
            elif c in OPS:
                # Если встретился оператор
                close_token()
                op = c
            else:
                token += c

    close_token()
    return current_value


result = parse('7 - sin(3.141592 * 0.75) + cos(2.718281)')
## Можете сравнить с корректным результатом, всё 1-в-1:
# result = 7 - math.sin(3.141592 * 0.75) + math.cos(2.718281)
print('Result:', result)
```